# Why does WebRequest fail with 404?

Tags: c#

Why does this code fail:

```
            //string url = "https://dl.pstmn.io/download/version/8.9.0/win64"; // works
        string url = "https://dl.pstmn.io/download/version/8.9.0/win32"; // Error 404 here, but works in FF or Chrome
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

but when I copy the URL into Firefox or Chrome the download actually works?

Comment: fails in browsers with a 404 here; are you sure it isn't working in Firefox/Chrome because of either caching, or you being logged in to their site, somehow? or having a cookie set that says (effectively) "yes, I'm actually trying to download things"? (note: `https://dl.pstmn.io/download/latest/win32` works)

Comment: That is the public download URL of the Postman software as found in the winget package repo, so what I am trying to say: definitely no login required and if it was, I wouldn't have an account. Just tested on an other machine to which I am connected via VPN: Download in FF works perfectly...

Comment: `Download in FF works perfectly` It doesn't here. You **definitely** tried in incognito?

Comment: is 'incognito mode' and 'private window' the same? works in 'private window' FF 90.0.2 Win10 21H1 - ah found it: 'incognito' is chrome: works for me as well

Comment: @frankkoch yes, same thing; but: multiple people are saying to you "that doesn't download - I get a 404 here" - maybe they're right! for all we know, it could be a broken CDN issue, or maybe it is intentionally geo-locked, but: the reason that web-request is failing with a 404 is *because the server is responding with a 404*, which is happening to multiple people from multiple places; we can't fix that with code - if there *is* an issue (and I'm not sure that there is), then that's something for the postman site admins to fix, presumably

Comment: @MarcGravell it really seems that there is a general problem with the download, but I am still wondering why even MSEdge (which cannot have the file in its cache, because I rarely use it) is able to download the file (Browsers don't share their cache?!) but the c# code reproducibly fails with 404... During troublshooting I think I saw something about TLSv1.3 in F12-Tools of FF - could this be related? (I am not a networking professional)

Comment: @frankkoch sure, TLS could be a factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `AutomaticDecompression` explicitly in `HttpWebRequest` -

```
string url = "https://dl.pstmn.io/download/version/8.9.0/win32";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req .AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I just discovered that the URL https://download.filezilla-project.org/client/FileZilla_3.55.0_win32-setup.exe has a similar problem, but it throws 403 in c# instead of 404 (and works in Browsers) You wouldn't happen to know the solution to that, too?

Comment: I just hit the API using postman and see what all headers are missing in the .NET one. You can try specifying `UserAgent` explicitly as well like `req.UserAgent = "MyAgent"`